# Using MAT to Understand Android Memory Leaks

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I'm writing my first app and trying to understand how to use MAT to find potential memory leaks. To keep things simple, I compiled the default *Hello World* app provided when starting a new project in Android Studio, i.e.,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

Nice and simple. Now immediately after launching this app on my tablet I take a heap dump (*heap-conv-1.hprof*) using DDMS and the `hprof-conv` conversion tool. I then rotate the tablet 20 times so the activity goes through a number of life cycles, after which I take another heap dump (*heap-conv-2.hprof*).

I load both heap dump files into MAT, compare them and do a regex for `.*MainActivity.*`. The result is:

[image: MainActivity objects shown in MAT]

Now there are 7 instances of the `MainActivity` after the rotations. Since I'm not doing anything with this app, am I right in thinking that this is purely because those instances haven't been GC'd yet? In which case , am I right in thinking that Android doesn't GC after an orientation change, and only when it needs more memory?

Comment: You're right, your device just did not run GC. DDMS has a button to force a GC, so I would suggest you to do it and get a third heap-dump:   certainly those 7 instances of MainActivity will decrease to 1.

Comment: Also, be aware that you can not be sure about when android will run GC. Even when you 'force' it, the system will has the last word about the best time to do it. [Here](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html) are a nice to create a dangerous leak using the Handler class

Comment: @Plinio.Santos Did a third heap dump after forcing a GC via DDMS, and yes you're right, the instances of MainActivity reduced to 1. Good to know, it's important to understand what is going on regarding GC if you're going to have any chance of finding memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Your code its not take that much of memory and doesn't leads to leaks..`Application` takes lot memory when you are loading large number of `bitmaps` into memory or holding large number of objects.and Using `Activity` context to long lived objects..

Here is the excellent video on memory leaks by google developer.[Memory leaks](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk)

you will get to know all the things after watching this..

Comment: Excellent video. Has given me far better understanding of memory leaks and the tools to use. However, it didn't really address my question of if GC occurs after an orientation change. In fact, the video insinuates that a GC does occur after oreinetation changes, but as I've been observing, and as @Plinio.Santos above comments, this is not the case. +1 though for the excellent link.

Comment: @JamesB there is not guarantee to GC when the orientation change..Android system detects when the memory is needed then it will GC the objects.there is no guarantee when it will run..